# How to add name/text to each table with matplotlib.pyplot, Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I used `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot 4 tables. For each table, there is an empty space at its top-left corner (between the first row label and the first column label), something like the mark below.

```
[Empty Space]   | 1st Col label | 2nd Col label | ...
1st row label   | data 1        | data 2        | ...
2st row label   | data 3        | data 4        | ...
...
```

I don't know how to add the text as name for each table in the empty space. Could you please help me?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [
    [100, 150, 50, 200],
    [200, 150, 150, 300],
    [50, 50, 50, 300],
    [50, 90, 80, 70],
]


col_labels = ['bbbbbbbbb1', 'bbbbbbbbb2', 'bbbbbbbbb3', 'bbbbbbbbb4']
row_labels = ['aaaaaaaa1', 'aaaaaaaa2', 'aaaaaaaa3', 'aaaaaaaa4']

low = 100
mid = 160
high = 200

cell_text = list()
cell_colors = list()
for row in data:
    row_text = list()
    row_color = list()
    for val in row:
        row_text.append('%.1f' % val)
        if val < low:
            color = 'g'
        elif low <= val < mid:
            color = 'y'
        elif mid <= val < high:
            color = 'b'
        else:  # val >= high
            color = 'r'
        row_color.append(color)
    cell_text.append(row_text)
    cell_colors.append(row_color)

n = 5
fig, axs = plt.subplots(n, 1)
for i in range(n):
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].table(
        cellText=cell_text,
        colLabels=col_labels,
        rowLabels=row_labels,
        cellColours=cell_colors,
        loc='center',
    )
    table_name = f'TableName {i}'  # How to add table name?

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last loop to:

```
for i in range(n):
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].table(
        cellText=cell_text,
        colLabels=col_labels,
        rowLabels=row_labels,
        cellColours=cell_colors,
        loc='center',
    )
    table_name = f'TableName {i}' + ' ' * 100
    axs[i].set_title(table_name, pad=20) # This line I added
plt.tight_layout()
```

You would have to use the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title` function and I added a pad to make the gap between the table name and the plot bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It indeed can add table name. However it is added to the top-mid position of each table. What I would like to have is at the top-left corner in the empty space marked by my example. Do you know how to do it? I tried `set_title(table_name, loc='left')`, it is still not in the correct position.

Comment: thanks again. But the `table_name` is still too high. I would like to have it at the same height as the column labels, just as the marked `[Empty Space]`.